# Sharing one Issues Log between multiple pages

Tags: 2013, web-part, sitepages

We have multiple teams that are working on separate aspects of the same project. Each team has their own sub-page of the project.

What I wanted to be able to do is to have one master Action Item/Issues log for the entire project, then each sub-page could see that list and add to it or update it as needed.

However, when I go into the sub-pages, SharePoint has the ability for me to create a new Issues Log for that page, but I can't seem to pull in or link to an existing one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding (correct me if I am wrong) you want to add a list view web-part on a page. for this follow below steps:

1. Navigate to sub-page and click on **Edit page** option from **Settings** (Gear icon a t the top of your page).
2. Click on **Add a Web Part**
3. Select the required list from the **Apps** categories.
4. Click on **Add** button.
5. Save the page.

Please refer below image to select the list from categories:

[image]

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your response, I think it's different.

So, here is what I was trying to do:
Create a master page with two sub-pages for each of the teams.
On the master page, create an issues log
For each of the sub-pages, have a filtered view of that master issues log for that team (this I was just going to do via a filter on a specific field).

What I'm struggling with, is that I can't seem to see the Issues Log that was created for the Master Site when I go to edit the sub-site.

Comment: By Master site you mean parent site(site collection)? Are you trying to add trying to add the list from parent site to sub-site as a list web part?

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly!

Comment: You cannot add the list from parent site to subsite as a list web part using SharePoint default capabilities.

Comment: Hi @Greg, does this answers your question? If yes, please upvote and accept it as an answer so that it will not be shown in unanswered question list.